# Make BottomSheet layout under ActionBar and hide part of views

Tags: android, android-layout, bottom-sheet

I have a problem structuring my layout. I need to implement a BottomSheet Layout that hides under the actionbar, but I have implemented UINavigations Jetpack + BottomSheetNavigation in my Activity. AppBar is created manually, ie it is not the default actionbar of android.

In the current Fragment I am implementing CoordinatorLayout for such a solution, so far I was able to implement normally, but the bottomsheet expands only to the actionbar.

I wanted to hide the buttons that are visible in peek mode of the bottomsheet layout.

Follows prints and excerpts of the layout.

[image: No interaction]
[image: On select item in recyclerview, show bottomsheet layout]
[image: Bottom sheet layout expanded]

Activity layout

```
   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="br.com.wari.wariconsumo.newapp.presentation.ui.sale.SaleActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_status_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_statusBar_nfcStatus"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:contentDescription="@string/statusBar_nfc_status"
                android:paddingEnd="5dp"
                android:paddingStart="6dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_circle"
                android:tint="@color/color_green" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_statusBar_nfcType"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:lines="1"
                android:text="@string/statusBar_NFCtype"
                android:textColor="@color/all_white" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_statusBar_batteryLevel"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:lines="1"
                android:text="@string/statusBar_battery_percentage"
                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                android:textColor="@color/all_white" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            local:theme="@style/WariTheme.ToolbarSearch"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"  />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_sale"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_navigation_sale"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/appbar"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph_sale" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_sale"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_navigation_colors"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_navigation_colors"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="selected"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation_sale" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Fragment Host Layout

```
  <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="br.com.wari.wariconsumo.newapp.presentation.ui.sale.fragments.menu.MenuFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/cl_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_products"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/layout_bottom_sheet_cart_products"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

layout bottom sheet

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ll_bottom_sheet_products"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:behavior_hideable="false"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="150dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/shadow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="6dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_gradient_top_shadow"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/ll_bottom_sheet" />

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:cardCornerRadius="1dp"
        app:cardElevation="20dp"
        android:elevation="20dp"
        >

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/cl_bottom_sheet_cart"
            android:background="@color/white_semi_transparent"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_amount_participant"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:text="@string/one_participant"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_small_total_value"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/view_indicator_swipe"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<!--            <ImageButton-->
<!--                android:id="@+id/ib_indicator_swipe"-->
<!--                android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
<!--                android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
<!--                android:layout_gravity="center"-->
<!--                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"-->
<!--                android:background="@null"-->
<!--                android:paddingTop="4dp"-->
<!--                android:paddingBottom="4dp"-->
<!--                android:src="@drawable/ic_indicator_swipe"-->
<!--                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"-->
<!--                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"-->
<!--                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />-->

            <View android:id="@+id/view_indicator_swipe"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="5dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/swipe_up_handle"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_indicator_swipe"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_currency_symbol"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:text="R$ "
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/tv_small_total_value"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/tv_small_total_value"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/tv_small_total_value" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_small_total_value"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:text="0,00"
                android:textSize="28sp"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/ib_confirm"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view_indicator_swipe" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_title_total_value"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:text="@string/value_to_pay"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@color/text_normal"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ib_participant_minus" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_coin"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/coin_real"
                android:textColor="@color/text_normal"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_large_total_value"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tv_large_total_value"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tv_large_total_value" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_large_total_value"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:text="@string/currency_zero"
                android:textColor="@color/text_dark"
                android:textSize="56sp"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_title_total_value" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/ib_participant_minus"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_white_selector"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_minus_user"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:paddingStart="4dp"
                android:paddingTop="7dp"
                android:paddingEnd="4dp"
                android:paddingBottom="7dp"
                android:tag="1"
                android:text="@string/decrease"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/text_normal"
                android:textSize="8sp"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ib_participant_plus"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_amount_participant"
                tools:ignore="SmallSp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/ib_participant_plus"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_white_selector"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_plus_user"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:paddingStart="4dp"
                android:paddingTop="7dp"
                android:paddingEnd="4dp"
                android:paddingBottom="7dp"
                android:tag="12"
                android:text="@string/increase"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/text_normal"
                android:textSize="8sp"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ib_note"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ib_participant_minus"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/ib_participant_minus"
                tools:ignore="SmallSp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/ib_note"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_blue_selector"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_message_outline"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:paddingStart="4dp"
                android:paddingTop="7dp"
                android:paddingEnd="4dp"
                android:paddingBottom="7dp"
                android:tag="13"
                android:text="@string/note"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/all_white"
                android:textSize="8sp"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ib_clear"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ib_participant_plus"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/ib_participant_plus"
                tools:ignore="SmallSp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/ib_clear"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_red_selector"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_trash"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:paddingStart="4dp"
                android:paddingTop="7dp"
                android:paddingEnd="4dp"
                android:paddingBottom="7dp"
                android:text="@string/clear"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/all_white"
                android:textSize="8sp"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ib_confirm"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ib_note"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/ib_note"
                tools:ignore="SmallSp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/ib_confirm"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_purple_selector"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_check"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:paddingStart="4dp"
                android:paddingTop="7dp"
                android:paddingEnd="4dp"
                android:paddingBottom="7dp"
                android:tag="7"
                android:text="@string/all_confirm"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/all_white"
                android:textSize="8sp"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ib_clear"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/ib_clear"
                tools:ignore="SmallSp" />

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rv_items_cart"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="96dp"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_large_total_value" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```